# Java Insertion Sort - copying values down array

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I need to make this insertion sort function essentially copy elements to the right until the value that needs to be moved would be in the correct position, however, with the code I'm using I typically end up getting garbage out, and have tried multiple iterations with the same result. I am at wits end as I see no reason why this shouldn't work.

```
public static void Sort(Comparable[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    Comparable temp = 0;
    int x;
    // Starting with the element at index 1...
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        // ...move to the left until we find one less
        // than the current element.
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (less(a[j], a[j - 1]))
            {
                temp = a[j];
                for(x = j; x > 0 && less(temp, a[x]); x--)
                {
                    a[x] = a[x - 1];
                }

                a[x] = temp;
                //exch(a, j, j - 1);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

less(a, b) checks to see if a < b, by the way.

Comment: hey, inner loop should go till zero and need not check i, it would be like `for (int j = i-1;j>=0;j--)`

Comment: I think your inner for loop (`for x = j;...`) is  literally overwriting the entire array with the starting value. Start there. Why is your logic so complicated with iterating forwards, then backwards, then backwards again with some other weird calls? Try to simplify, look up the algorithm for insertion sort. It's not this complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first iteration of the innermost loop, in this condition: `x > 0 && less(temp, a[x])` you are checking whether the value you just stored in temp... is less than the value you just stored in temp, referred to by another name. This will always return false, causing the loop to never start. The end result is that the entire method is an expensive no-op. If you're testing it by sending in a randomly jumbled array, you'll end up with the array still randomly jumbled when it's done.

To fix this, simply subtract 1 from the index in that condition, making it `x > 0 && less(temp, a[x - 1])`.

The rest of your code looks correct, I think, though the loop with `j` is redundant and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
public static void Sort(Comparable[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    Comparable temp = 0;
    int x;
    // Starting with the element at index 1...
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        // ...move to the left until we find one less
        // than the current element.
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (less(a[j], a[j - 1]))
            {
                temp = a[j];
                for(x = j; x > 0 && less(temp, a[x-1]); x--)
                {
                    a[x] = a[x - 1];
                }

                a[x] = temp;
                //exch(a, j, j - 1);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}
```